# Initialize function on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a js file where there is a function with multiple parameters

```
function initSlider(slider, sliderRow, slides, CLONES_COUNT, doAutoPlay) {
. . .
}
```

And I want to use this function on different pages, but with slightly different parameters, let's say for one of the pages there will be

```
initSlider(slider, sliderRow, slides, (slides.length < 2) ? 0 : 1, slides.length > 1)
```

The question is, how do I call this initialization function on the page itself?

The usual page for laravel, blade.php where at the end there is a section with scripts

```
@section('scripts')
<script src="/js/slider.js"></script>
@endsection
```

im try

```
@yield('scripts')
@stack('slider-script')
</body>
```

```
@section('scripts')
other scripts
@endsection

@push('slider-script')
 <script src="/js/slider.js"></script>
@endpush

@push('slider-script')
<script>
   initSlider(slider, sliderRow, slides, (slides.length < 2) ? 0 : 1, slides.length > 1);
</script>
@endpush
```

but nothing works, error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: initSlider is not defined

Comment: Use [Stacks](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#stacks), fill them per `.blade.php` file with the parameters you need

Comment: @brombeer I tried it, but it didn't work, apparently I misunderstood something

Comment: You are not allowed to use `@stack('script')` and `@push('script')` in the same view in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You could put all Javascript code between `@section('script')` and `@endsection`.

slider.js

```
function initSlider(slider, sliderRow, slides, CLONES_COUNT, doAutoPlay) {
    console.log(slider);
}
```

blade

```
@section('script')
<script src="/js/slider.js"></script>
<script>
    slides = [1,2];
    initSlider(1, 2, slides, (slides.length < 2) ? 0 : 1, slides.length > 1);
</script>
@endsection
```

If you want to use `stack` method:

1. In your layout php file (e.g. `app.blade.php`)

   ```
   @stack('scripts')
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. In your current blade file:

   ```
   @push('scripts')
    <script src="/js/slider.js"></script>
   @endpush

   @push('scripts')
   <script>
      slides = [1,2];
      initSlider(1, 2, slides, (slides.length < 2) ? 0 : 1, slides.length > 1);
   </script>
   @endpush
   ```

Either way should work.

Comment: get error `Uncaught ReferenceError: initSlider is not defined`

Comment: Did you check the path of `slider.js`? It should work.

Comment: all paths are correct, everything should work, but I still get this error

Comment: Maybe the function `initSlider(slider, sliderRow, slides, (slides.length < 2) ? 0 : 1, slides.length > 1);` itself needs to be called in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

If Phil's answer doesn't work. There is one possibility: You haven't declared `@yield('script')` anywhere in your document. `@yield` goes with `@section` and `@stack` goes with `@push`. Don't let them confuse you.

Comment: I already have `@yield('scripts')` and I am confused how to do everything since nothing works (

Comment: @meow Check my comment above, you are not allowed to have  @stack('script') and @push('script') in the same Blade template

Comment: I separated them, added to the post how everything is done for me now